# Extract an integer in a line of string

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

I am having a bit of an issue with extracting a number from a text file. Basically, it looks like this (all on one line; split here for slightly more readability):

```
[{"id":1,"width":720,"height":480,"longitude":20.104258199768,"timestamp":1510690197540,"frame_content":"some other informations...},
{"id":2,"width":720,"height":480,"longitude":20.104258199768,"timestamp":1510690197552,"frame_content":"some other informations...},
{"id":3,"width":720,"height":480,"longitude":20.104258199768,"timestamp":1510690197556,"frame_content":"some other informations...},
{"id":4,"width":720,"height":480,"longitude":20.104258199768,"timestamp":1510690197558,"frame_content":"some other informations...},
and so on.....]
```

What I would like to do is to extract all the values after the timestamp label. The thing is that my **file is made of only one single line** which makes it a bit tricky and I don't think I can change that. I have tried the `sed` and `grep` commands after looking up on the internet for a solution but it's been unsuccessful so far.

I would appreciate any sort of help on that matter :)

Thank you!

Comment: Is the string a proper JSON document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
grep -oP '"timestamp":\s*\K\d+' filename
```

doesn't matter if everything is on one line, it will search for all occurences of numbers after the string "timestamp:"

result :

```
1510690197540
1510690197552
1510690197556
1510690197558
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the file is a well-formed JSON file, you should be using a JSON parser to parse it.

Using the [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) JSON parser on a file:

```
$ jq '.[] | .timestamp' filename.json
1510690197540
1510690197552
1510690197556
1510690197558
```

The expression `.[] | .timestamp` creates an implicit loop over all objects in the array, and extracts the `timestamp` value from each.

It could also be written

```
$ jq '.[].timestamp' file.json
```

---

Unrelated:

To find the `id` of the object with the maximum `timestamp`:

```
$ jq 'max_by(.timestamp).id' file.json
4
```

To pretty-print your JSON file:

```
$ jq . file.json
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Indeed, this file comes from a JSON file but it is not in the JSON format. I basically copied/pasted the content from an html page to a txt file.

I tried changing the txt format with a JSON format and run the line you gave me but I end up with the following error:

parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0

Comment: @Einsiedler Well, that could be any number of reasons for that, but not quoting a value may be the main reason. I had to close the half-opened strings in your example to be able to run the commands in my answer (and add a missing `}` at the end), for example. I assumed it was you who had tried to cut down on the amount of information though.

Comment: Ok, I managed to make it work, must have missed something. It's perfect :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

awk solution:

```
awk -F, '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i~/timestamp/) { split($i,slt,":");print slt[2]  } } }' filename
```

result:

```
1510690197540
1510690197552
1510690197556
1510690197558
```

Loop over each of the fields delimited by a comma and then take the field and pattern match against timestamp. If there is a match, split the field using : into an array slt. Then print the second element of the array.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it seems to be working but how do you define NF?

Comment: @Einsiedler `NF` is a variable that `awk` itself sets to the number of fields on the current input line. The number of fields depends on `FS`, the field separator, which Raman sets to a comma on the command line with `-F,`.